# What technique can I use to get the model associated with a rendered partial view in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building a search screen dynamically, and it's presented a problem I'm unsure about how to solve.

For simplicity sake, let's assume I have 3 entity types: A person, a dog and a car. These are listed in a dropdown on the search form, and based on what the user selects, the controller returns the relevant partial view which has search criteria html controls specific to the type selected:

```
User selects 'Dog' from dropdown:
   - Dynamically renders a pre-built partial view with search fields: Pet Name, Breed.
User selects 'Person' from dropdown:
   - Dynamically renders a pre-built partial view with search fields: Name, Surname
```

etc.

I have a Person, Dog and Car table in my database which I need to search. I can't figure out how to:

1) Associate a model with the relevant partial view (containing entity-specific fields)

2) Retrieve the model from the controller and call the appropriate database functions.

So in my mind I'd like to do something like:

```
    public ActionResult DoSearch()
    {
        switch ( theEntityTypeSelected )
        {
            case EntityType.Person :
                {
                    var personModel someLogic.GetPersonPartialViewModel(); // The model containing the search criteria fields and values
                    var searchResults = db.Person.Where(x => x.Name == personModel.Name && x.Surname == personModel.Surname);
                    return View(searchResults);
                }
        }
    }
```

What options do I have to accomplish this? Perhaps there's even a better way than the example I laid out above?

Comment: Why wouldn't use want to use strongly typed views for each? You can extract most of the common code into partials to re-use. I can think of a way to do it using a generic interface but it will limit your functionality.

Comment: Why don't you have a search text box, and a dropdown for which type to search.  Then, with an ajax call, send the parameters to the action in the controller, and return your common partial view with the search result.

Comment: @JamieRees I do have strongly typed partial views. I return them to the main view and they get rendered that way. My problem is that I need to somehow to take the fields in the partial view and get a model out of it with the fields + values, if that makes any sense. May I see your suggestion of the interface please?

Comment: I'm not 100% following, You have a 'main' view with 3 different partial views. and you want the appropriate partial to render depending on your Model type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example of how to dynamically render a partial, based on a selected item in a dropdown.

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public SearchViewModel()
    {
        this.SearchObjectTypes = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public IList<SelectListItem> SearchObjectTypes { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Partial()
    {
        var viewModel = new SearchViewModel();

        viewModel.SearchObjectTypes.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Please select...", Value = "" });
        viewModel.SearchObjectTypes.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Dog", Value = "Dog" });
        viewModel.SearchObjectTypes.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Person", Value = "Person" });

        return View(viewModel);
    }

public ActionResult GetDogSearchView()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("_DogSearch");
    }

    return View("_DogSearch");
}
```

**Main search view**

```
@model ModelBindingList.Controllers.SearchViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Partial";
}

@Html.DropDownList("SearchObjects", Model.SearchObjectTypes)

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="SearchFields">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
}
@section scripts{

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#SearchObjects").change(function () {
            var searchObjectType = $(this).find(":selected").text();

            switch (searchObjectType) {
                case "Dog":
                    $.get('@Url.Action("GetDogSearchView", "Home")', function (data) {
                        $('#SearchFields').html(data);
                    });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
}
```

**_DogSearch.cshtml**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter dog breed..."/>
```

When you choose an item from the dropdown, a `GET` request is made for the partial view. But, one issue you will have is how to pass the search fields back to the controller.

Since you will let the user search for dog, person, etc then the input viewmodel will need all the fields (Name, Breed, etc) and the type of object being searched (Dog, Person) stated also. I'm not sure how that will work cleanly for you.